# How to remove an item from json stored in database using eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Model which stores data in the as follows:

```
{
            "id": "1f280536-3aa2-45d9-8f23-41c27a26c8bf",
            "setting": {
                "item 1": "first item",
                "item 2": "second item",
                "logo": {
                    "small": "1anFsLsviRf_8zI5u8x5BY3OSf-jWAWkE"
                }
            },
}
```

As you can see `setting` is a json which contains another nested json `logo`. I have a destroy controller method for removing a single logo from the `logo` json but when I try to mutate `logo` I got `ErrorException: Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Models\Company::$setting has no effect in file`  error. I had the same error when storing new logo but I solved it using `array_merge`

```
 $company->setting = array_merge($company->setting, array("logo"=>array_merge($company->setting["logo"], array($request->size=>$file_id))));
```

How can I resolve my issue when removing single key value pair form `logo` json?

Answer (score 0):

You can `json_decode` company setting then remove the `logo` key

```
$setting = json_decode($company->setting, true);

unset($setting['setting']['logo']);

$company->setting = json_encode($setting);
```

Comment: I have already tried doing that but "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in file" error appears. $company->setting is already an array, no need to decode.

Comment: Good so you needed the second part !

Comment: I have tried "unset" method but I still get "Indirect modification of overloaded property" error.